# Safely URL escape emails with string templates in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, url

I have some Kotlin code that is sending email addresses that are URL query encoded, so certain characters must be escaped. However there are errors because some valid email addresses contain "$" or "${expression}". For example:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder

fun main() {
    val encodedEmail = URLEncoder.encode("bademail_${2*4}@gmail.com", Charsets.UTF_8)
    println(encodedEmail)
}
```

returns:

```
bademail_8%40gmail.com
```

When I need it to return:

```
bademail_%24%7B2*4%7D%40gmail.com
```

Note that these email addresses are coming from an external source so I cannot just manually change the email address by adding an escape character like so:

```
val escapedTemplateEmail = "bademail_\${2*4}@gmail.com"
// we are stuck with this
val troublesomeEmail = "bademail_${2*4}@gmail.com"
```

Comment: Which external source are you reading from? Interpolation should only be happening when a String is declared. I tested reading a file which has this email address; once read, the `${2*4}` was treated as is, and the characters were escaped properly.